# LibreOffice writer converting to PDF problem

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, libreoffice

I'm using Lubuntu 20.04 and when I try to convert LibreOffice Writer to PDF everything and texts missing and there are some unknown characters in PDF file (see image)
[image: output PDF]

Edition: 
Libbre office version: LibreOffice 6.4.7.2 40(Build:2)
There is no any confidential information in the original file. 
I tried to save a file with "Hello world" text but the output PDF was empty! 
Then I tried to save a new (.odb and .docx) file with Persian characters but there was nothing in output file again.
Then I tried one of my old .docx files with Persian characters and saw unknown characters again in my PDF.

Comment: Provided that it ***does not*** contain any confidential information, can you share the original Writer document?

Comment: ... and [edit] your question with the version of LO